# How to debug the identation levels in a Python program?

Tags: python

I've just started learning Python. I'm using MU Editor and I can't get past the first "if statement." I click run, then enter "Joe" and it keeps asking me "Who are you?".

Am I correct in entering this input in the run section? Or should it go in the REPL or text editor section?

```
while True:
  print('Who are you?')
  name = input()
  if name != 'Joe':
    continue
    print('Hello, Joe. What is the password? (It is a fish.)')
  password = input()
    if password == 'swordfish':
      break
print('Access granted.')
```

Comment: The `print()` line shouldn't be inside the `if`.

Comment: What you have posted would raise an indentation error.

Comment: The second `if` statement needs to be at the same indentation level as `password = input()`

Answer (score 0):

so if you're using python3 make sure you have this in line 1 of your code. `#!/usr/bin/env python3`

Then when running the file enter this into your command line. `python3 "filename.py"`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

name = input('Who are you?: ')
if name == "Joe":
    print(f"Hello, {name}.")
    password = input('What is the password? (It is a fish.)')
    if password == 'swordfish':
        print('Access granted.')
    else:
        print('Access denied.')
else:
    print(f"Sorry {name}, I don't know you.")
```

I cleaned up your code a bit as the `while True` statement wasn't necessary. Let me know if you have any questions.